# AWS Opsworks skip setup process on instance start

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I want to create few micro instances to deploy branches and pre-release staging applications.
I want them to be powered-up on demand fast for few hours and once testing is complete again stop them.
Since there is EBS backed option for instances, the data on disk is preserved and it makes no sense to run whole setup process from scratch - it takes time, also our custom recipes fail on attempt to install the same software again.
I tried to power up them from EC2, they power up very fast and available, but in opsworks they remain stopped hence not available for deployments.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer on AWS forum.
Apparently, all chef recipes should be designed with idea, that they could be ran unlimited amount of times. For example if the package in recipe exists - it just does nothing or launches tool like apt-get install and it does not fail.
And there is no (official) way to avoid overhead of running recipes on start each time.